# At least two birthdays in a month

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are 4 people and each person has an associated birth month. How many ways are there so that at least 2 people share the same birth month?

My first instinct is that it's $12\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10$ but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 5):

$$(\text{The number of ways at least 2 people share the same birth month}) =$$
$$(\text{The number of all possible arrangements of birth months})-$$
$$(\text{The number of ways no 2 people share the same birth month})$$
$$=(12\times12\times12\times 12)-(12\times 11\times 10\times 9)=20736-11880=8856$$